# Verify if string in array script problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, verify

I am trying to verify if a string is in an array with javascript. I searched around and found the below code (it has some of my alterations too). I have it set up so that it alerts when it succeeds and fails. When it succeeds, every time it is run after that, it is stuck on the success, until the page is refreshed. If it fails, the same thing happens. What can make it start fresh every time it is run?

```
function urlVerify(a, b) {
    for (var j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        if (a[j].match (b)) {
            ...
            alert('found');
            return j;
        }
    } 
    ...
    alert('notfound');
    return -1;
}
```

The code that contains the array and calls the function is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var urlPlain = window.location.hash.replace(/[#/]+/g, "");

    var pageIndex = [
        'home',
        'contact'
    ]       

    urlVerify(pageIndex, urlPlain);

});
```

The normal website url would go as follows: `www.example.com/#/home`

Then the urlPlain variable simplifies it to be: `home`

Comment: This code looks sound to me. It has no side effects. There is nothing to 'fresh'en up.

Comment: You should include the part of your code where the array is defined and where you are calling the `urlVerify` function. Have you tried to abstact this code into a simple test case?

Comment: I added the code. I have tried the code in a simple test case and it still worked the same way. I would like it to forget whether or not the string was in the array every single time I call the urlVerify function.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? You're using jQuery, so there is jQuery.inArray() that does exactly the same thing. Another note: `a[j].match(b)` would be truthy if a[j] is "homepage" and b is only "home", I don't think that this is how you want it to behave.

Comment: What's in the ... part? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean once it succeeds it is stuck. Unless you refresh the page the urlPlain will not change hence you will be "stuck". If you are navigating by some ajaxy/hash means you need to "refresh" your urlPlain (capture it when a navigation event happens) and rerun your urlVerify

Comment: @Niko I was not aware that inArray existed, I will use that now.

Comment: @James The ... part is other code that does not change how this function works.

Answer (score 1):

To remove everything up to the "#/" you need:

```
var lastBit = url.replace(/.*#\//, '')
```

The above will return everything after the last "#/". But if you just want the last bit, why include the hash?

To see if the word is in the array, depending on the string, you may be able to use:

```
var hasLastBit = wordArray.join().match(lastBit);
```

or a more accurate version:

```
var re = new RegExp('(^|\s)' + lastBit + '(\s|$)');
var hasLastBit = re.test(wordArray.join(' '));
```

Comment: I am just reading the hash, so I have no need to clear everything before the hash, and I am now using jQuery.inArray() plus one other fix that has eliminated my problem.